# How to display text of listbox items in the canvas with Python3x tkiner?

Tags: python-3.x, canvas, listbox, tkinter

I am trying to display the text of the selected item of a listbox into the canvas. When I bind the listbox to a helper event handler, it throws Attribute Error: CLASS object has no attribute "HELPER EVENT HANDLER".

What I want is as follows:

1) When double clicking an item in the listbox to the left, its text should be displayed on the canvas. This particular line of code is causing all the troulbe to me.

```
lstbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.OnDouble)
```

Could you please help me fixing this error?

2) I believe that there must be a way to make the lines' height on the listbox larger than they appear in my application. However, I don't know how to do it. I tried providing several options but these options are not recognized by tkinter. Could you please suggest to me how to do it?

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
languages = ['Mandarin', 'English', 'French']
class LanguageFamilies(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        canv = tk.Canvas(self, width=675, height=530, bg="white", relief="sunken")
        canv.config(scrollregion=(0,0,300,650), highlightthickness=0)
        canv.pack(side="right", expand=True, fill="both")

        # Create scroll bar
        sbar = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        canv.config(yscrollcommand=sbar.set)
        sbar.config(command=canv.yview)
        sbar.pack(side="right", fill="both")

        # Create Scroll List
        lstbox = tk.Listbox(self, width=240, height=530, relief="sunken", font="Courier")
        lst_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        lstbox.config(yscrollcommand=lst_scrollbar.set)
        lst_scrollbar.config(command=lstbox.yview)
        lstbox.pack(side="left", expand=True, fill="both")
        lst_scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="both")
        lstbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.OnDouble) # THIS IS THE LINE CAUSING THE ERROR

        # Add items to the lstbox
        i = 0
        while i < len(languages):
            lstbox.insert(i, languages[i])
            i += 1

        # Create a text inside canvas
        canv_id = canv.create_text(50, 50, font="Times 14", anchor="nw")
        msg = "This is a text inside canvas."
        canv.insert(canv_id, "end", msg)

        #Binding Handler
        def OnDouble(self, event):
            self.widget = event.widget
            selection = self.widget.curselection()
            content = self.widget.get(selection[0])
            print("You selected", content)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("930x530")
    root.title("Language Families")
    LanguageFamilies(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

And this is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Python33/new_stack_overflow.py", line 43, in <module>
LanguageFamilies(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
File "C:/Python33/new_stack_overflow.py", line 23, in __init__
lstbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.OnDouble)
AttributeError: 'LanguageFamilies' object has no attribute 'OnDouble'
```

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: Your ndentation looks very strange. Your `__init__` function only has a one line, then the rest is outdented. Is that intentional? Perhaps that is the cause. There are other indentation errors -code at the same level as the `def` statement. Maybe you have a mixture of tabs and spaces, making the code look different to you than to the computer.

Comment: @BryanOakley, thank you very much for your kind comment. I think the indentation problem has been caused by copying the code to the web browser. I have shared the code from google drive. Please have a look at it here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzk3iitPNBruYnpKMFF4b1Fhbzg/view?usp=sharing Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please fix the code in the question. That google drive or that file might not always be around.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I will fix it now and let you know when it is ready.

Comment: @BryanOakley, I have fixed the code and reformulated the question altogether in a new question. Please have a look at it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27612955/why-tkinter-binding-function-cannot-be-defined-inside-the-main-class  Once you see the new question, please inform me so that I can delete this question. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Why did you create a new question? You're not asking anything new. You should have updated this question and delete the other.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**HERE IS THE COMPLETE AND CORRECT ANSWER! BELOW IS STAGES OF SOLVING THE PROBLEM.**

1. Bryan's suggestions of decreasing the indentation of the OnDouble event handler by one level were the first steps to the solution.
2. The crucial thing I learnt from this experience is that printing the text of a listbox on the canvas directly is not the right option. Rather, the best option is to put a text widget on the canvas so that manipulating text matters will be much easier. I came up to this conclusion after watching a nice video tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kekZZDz99PY). As such, a text widget was defined ontop of the canvas. An if condition was used to control what to print on the text-canvas and how many times it should be printed - (in this case, only onece exactly the same as an electronic dictionary - which is my application).

Here is the COMPLETE WORKING code:

```
import tkinter as tk
languages = ['Mandarin', 'English', 'French']
global counter
counter = 1
class LanguageFamilies(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        global canv, canv_id # IN ORDER TO MAKE THEM ACCESSIBLE TO OnDouble EVENT HANDLER
        canv = tk.Canvas(self, width=675, height=530, bg="white", relief="sunken")
        canv.config(scrollregion=(0,0,300,650), highlightthickness=0)
        canv.pack(side="right", expand=True, fill="both")

        # Create scroll bar
        sbar = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        canv.config(yscrollcommand=sbar.set)
        sbar.config(command=canv.yview)
        sbar.pack(side="right", fill="both")

        # Create Scroll List
        lstbox = tk.Listbox(self, width=240, height=530, relief="sunken", font="Courier")
        lst_scrollbar = tk.Scrollbar(self)
        lstbox.config(yscrollcommand=lst_scrollbar.set)
        lst_scrollbar.config(command=lstbox.yview)
        lstbox.pack(side="left", expand=True, fill="both")
        lst_scrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="both")
        lstbox.bind("<Double-Button-1>", self.OnDouble) 

        # Add items to the lstbox
        i = 0
        while i < len(languages):
            lstbox.insert(i, languages[i])
            i += 1

        # Create a text inside canvas
        global textmatter
        textmatter = tk.Text(canv) # THE TEXT SHOULD BE PRINTED ON THE CANVAS
        textmatter.insert("end", "Double-click on a language on the left to view information.")
        textmatter.pack()



    #Binding Handler, ONE INDENTATION LEVEL IS REMOVED AS PER BRYAN'S SUGGESTION
    def OnDouble(self, event):
        global counter
        self.widget = event.widget
        selection = self.widget.curselection()
        content = self.widget.get(selection[0])
        if counter == 1:
            textmatter.delete(1.0, "end") # CLEAR THE TEXT WHICH IS DISPLAYED AT FIRST RUNNING
            textmatter.insert("end", content)
            counter += 1 #ONE ITEM HAS BEEN SELECTED AND PRINTED SUCCESSFULLY
        elif counter > 1: 
            textmatter.delete(1.0, "end")
            textmatter.insert("end", content)
            counter = 1 # RESET THE COUNTER SO THAT NEXT SELECTED ITEM DISPLAYS PROPERLY





if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("930x530")
    root.title("Language Families")
    LanguageFamilies(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

***That is it. I hope this post will be of help to you!***

**SALAM,**

**Mohammed**

Comment: It's highly unusual to pack a text widget in a canvas. I don't even know why you're using a canvas at all. Also, if you're using a class there's no reason to make any variables global -- they can be attributes of the class.

Comment: @BryanOakley I am not a professional programmer. I am a Ph.D student in Linguistics. But I am interested in learning programming by myself because I need some programs in my Ph.D. project. I could have a professional programmer design the software for me, but what is the benefit if I don't know hwo the software works. I learnt Python online through coursera website.  I am not a professional programmer like you or your peers.  Whatever the case, I really appreciate your interactions with my post. They were so helpful.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that the def for `OnDouble` is defined *inside* `__init__`, making it not a class method but a method inside the scope of `__init__`. You need to remove one level of indentation for `OnDouble`.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful suggestions, Bryan! I removed the edits on the original code. It is now the same which was throwing an error. Further, I kept trying to get the text printed on the canvas until I could do it, although clumzily. I have posted the code as a self-aswer to my question. Thank you again and Merry Christmas!

Comment: Finally, I could fix the code and get the text printed on the canvas as desired. Thank you so much for your kind help! Merry Christmas!